# Run python flask on EC2 in the background

Tags: amazon-ec2, flask, start-stop-daemon

I have small app created on python flask and deployed on EC2 aws machine, when I do ssh to ec2 machine and starts flask, it works, but when I terminate the session the flask dies, I can run it using nohup. What is the best way to make it independent of ssh session and run it continuously.

Comment: Thanks alot for this question too

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several options:

1. `nohup python app.py &`
2. use `screen`
3. run `supervisord`[(link)](http://supervisord.org) on system startup and control all through it (pythonic way :))

[nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) means: do not terminate this process even when the stty is cut off.

& at the end means: run this command as a background task.

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer